# Can we combine Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints and Spring Boot REST Web Service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-endpoints

I had written a Google App Engine application two years back with App Engine Cloud Endpoints as well as Datastore (Java application).

Now, I have to integrate an application which is written in Spring Boot.

After integration, my expectation is that Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints should work fine as well as the Spring Boot application.

More info: Integration means, two years back I had written an application using this sample project:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/7f5772f91a203ce266804cfbe89429e2bb026273/appengine/endpoints-v1-helloworld

Now, I have a Spring Boot application which is similar to this: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/demos/springboot

My question: Is it possible like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"? Please describe your scenario more fully.

Comment: I have updated the question, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: By integration do you mean: (1) The two apps (old Endpoints app and new Spring boot app) are communicating with each other over the network. (2) You want to add Spring boot to your old Endpoints app. (3) You want to add Endpoints to your Spring boot app.

Comment: (2) and (3) are correct. since spring boot is latest project more keen on (3)

Comment: @SunilRk Did you manage to get it to work ?

Comment: Not possible, both are different flavors. I went with creating new springboot application as  i dont have to depend on google app engine which was tightly coupled. After 4 years of app engine relation i understood that your application should be very loosely coupled with environment so that u can migrate to any of the cloud anytime,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the management features of Endpoints with a Spring Boot application, this is officially supported on App Engine Flex. It's theoretically possible on App Engine Standard, but is not a supported scenario. If you want an application that is using the API framework and Spring Boot, I suppose it is possible, though I don't know why you would want to use two different web frameworks. It would be far more efficient to use one or the other.

Comment: hi, Thanks for the reply. Old application with endpoints is live and having huge code, at this point of difficult to migrate whole application to spring boot. Hence finding a ways.